# In heat conduction, why does the distance energy travels vary with $\sqrt t$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics

In the following setup, $T_{a}$ is at a higher temperature than $T_{b}$; additionally, $T+{b}$ is fixed, so $T_{a}$ will only ever approach $T_{b}$. It can be shown that the difference in temperature between both slabs follows an exponentially decaying function given by: $\Delta T = \Delta T_{initial}*e^\frac{-t}{\tau}$ where $\tau$ is given by $R_{thermal}C$

[image]

A simple expression for the value of $R_{thermal}C$, using a rectangular prism as a model, can be derived as follows:

[image]

Where $\rho$ is density, $c$ the specific heat capacity and $lA$ the cross sectional area * length,

$C = c \rho* lA$

and where $k$ is the heat conductivity, $l$ the length and $A$ the area, $R_{thermal} = \frac{l}{kA}$

We find, multiplying these terms out, that $R_{thermal}C \propto d^2$

---

While I can accept this expression, I can't extend it to reason **why the distance that thermal energy has travelled varies with $\sqrt t$**. The first thing I don't understand is "how do we represent the distance that energy travels?" And secondly, doesn't $\tau$'s dependence on $d^2$ only imply that, at times proportional to $\tau$ (which are also multiples of $d^2$), "classic" scalings with respect to $e$ take place $(e^-1, e^-2, ...)$ in exponential part of the equation given above.

$\Delta T = \Delta T_{initial}*e^\frac{-t}{\tau}$

Comment: Don't understand everything that you've said above, but as for the main question of the distance that thermal energy travels goes as sqrt(t), isn't that just a consequence of the random walk nature of the phonons or electrons carrying the heat energy?

Comment: Clarified the question's details. Sorry oh. I wanted to understand the distance travelled as a consequence of $\tau$ or $RC$'s dependence on $d^2$